# Point subfolder to root without changing URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm translating my website and will use this structure:

- www.mywebsite.com --> EN version
- www.mywebsite.com/es --> ES version
- www.mywebsite.com/fr --> FR version
- ...

From a maintenance perspective, I would like to use the exact same PHP files for all languages. I will just get the URL, see which language code is in the URL and load the correct language from my database. That way, I don't have to maintain different files with basically the same code.

So, ideally, I want `www.mywebsite.com/es` to load `www.mywebsite.com/index.php` but without redirecting to it: the URL in the address bar should still contain `/es`.

In the same manner, `www.mywebsite.com/es/whatever/other.php` should load `www.mywebsite.com/whatever/other.php`, but with `/es` in the URL.

Is this possible in .htaccess?

What I'm going for right now is just putting this in `/es/index.php`:

```
include('../index.php');
```

...which works fine, but it's a bit heavier to maintain because I have to create all these dummy pages in all language folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this code in site root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(es|fr)$ /$1/ [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(?:es|fr)/$ index.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(?:es|fr)/(.+)$ $1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Awesome! This seems to work brilliantly and saves me a ton of work! Thanks a lot! One additional question: SEO wise, is there a difference between this approach and actually placing files in the subfolders? I mean, does Google know/care that the actual loaded URL is without the `/es` for example? Because I want it to scrape all versions, of course.

Comment: Not at all, No search engine would ever know that your actual URL is without `/es` or without `/fr`

Comment: One thing I noticed with the above code, is that browsers don't append the `/` automatically. For example, if you would you to `facebook.com/events`, your browsers will automatically make it into `facebook.com/events/` . I want this to happen with `/es` and `/fr` too, because otherwise they turn up as different URLs in Google Search Console, so I guess Google sees `www.mysite.com/es` as a different page as `www.mysite.com/es/` , which I don't want of course.

Comment: ok check updated answer for adding a trailing slash in front of `/es` or `/fr`

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite all incoming requests to you index.php if any file or directory is not found on your server. Then extract the language code from the url on index.php and fetch correct info from the database.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

this should work